# Perl matching multidimensional array elements

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, pattern-matching

Im not getting any output, anyone get where the issue lies,
matching or calling?
(The two subarrays in the multidimensional array have the same length.)

```
//Multidimensional array,
//Idarray = Fasta ID, Seqarray = "ATTGTTGGT" sequences
@ordarray = (\@idarray, \@seqarray);


//This calling works

print $ordarray[0][0] , "\n";
print $ordarray[1][0] , "\n", "\n";

// Ordarray output = "TTGTGGCACATAATTTGTTTAATCCAGAT....."
```

User inputs a search string, loop iterates the sequence dimension,
and counts amount of matches. Prints number of matches and the corresponding ID from the ID dimension.

```
 //The user input-searchstring
    $sestri = <>;

for($r=0;$r<@idarray;$r++) {

    if ($sestri =~ $ordarray[1][$r]  ){

        print $ordarray[0][$r] , "\n";
        $counts = () = $ordarray[0][$r] =~ /$sestri/g;  
        print "number of counts: ", $counts ;

    }
```

Comment: First of all, `use strict;`  and `use warnings;` on top of your script. Then, comments begin with `#`  not `//`.

Comment: `$sestri =~ $ordarray[1][$r] ` might not be doing what was intended either. It's a regular expression match, but it's checking if `$ordarray[1][$r]` is a substring of the search, rather than the other way around (which would be more normal)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with this:

```
$sestri = <>;
```

That may well not be doing what you intended - your comment says "user specified search string" but that's not what that operator does.

What it does, is open the *filename* you specifed on the command line, and 'return' the first line.

I would suggest that if you want to grab a search string from command line you want to do it via `@ARGV`

E.g.

```
my ( $sestri ) = @ARGV; # will give first word.
```

However, please please please switch on `use strict` and `use warnings`. You should *always* do this prior to posting on a forum for assistance.

I would also question quite why you need a two dimensional array with two elements in it though. It seems unnecessary.

Why not instead make a hash, and key your "fasta ids" to the sequence?

E.g.

```
my %id_of;
@id_of{@seqarray} = @idarray;

my %seq_of;
@seq_of{@id_array} = @seqarray;
```

I think this would suit your code a bit better, because then you don't have to worry about the array indicies at all.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($sestri) = @ARGV;

my %id_of;
@id_of{@seqarray} = @idarray;

foreach my $sequence ( keys %id_of ) {

    ##NB - this is a pattern match, and will be 'true'
    ## if $sestri is a substring of $sequence
    if ( $sequence =~ m/$sestri/ ) {
        print $id_of{$sequence}, "\n";
        my $count = () = $sequence =~ m/$sestri/g;
        print "number of counts: ", $count, "\n";
    }
}
```

I've rewritten it a bit, because I'm not entirely understanding what your code is doing. It *looks* like it's substring matching in `@seqarray` but then returning the count of matching elements in `@idarray` I don't think that makes sense, but if it does, then amend according to your needs.

Comment: `<>` returns `<STDIN>` if `@ARGV` is empty